# OpenCV: Computational efficiency of filter2D function

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

If I want to perform convolution of an image with a kernel in OpenCV, I can use the `filter2D` function. Another option is to create my own filter using for loops as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13981699/5022962).

Would filter2D be faster than the code presented in the post? If yes, what makes it faster?

I tried looking at the [code for filter2d](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp) but couldn't understand. I'm new to openCV and any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Try profiling it! Usually OpenCV code is much faster then naive implementation, since a lot of cool programmers optimized it really well, also to use hardware acceleration in some cases.

Comment: Most likely it will be way faster. There are quite non-intuitive ways of coding convolution/matrix multiplication than speed up the computation a lot and openCV uses them. Mathematicians work in those things a lot.
Check for exmaple matrix multiplication algorithms: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Sub-cubic_algorithms

Comment: I also think it should be faster that's why I try to perform tasks using filters as far as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of OpenCV is, in fact, much faster than the naive approach!  For convolutions, they often use one of these two fundamental optimizations:

1. **Separable convolution.**  Takes advantage of the "associative property of convolution" for certain types of kernels.  For an `M-by-N` image and `P-by-Q` kernel, the naive approach is `M*N*P*Q`.  If the kernel is separable you can do it in `M*N(P+Q)`.  That's huge!  You will notice OpenCV's filter2d source takes advantage of this when possible.  Read more about it [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).
2. The **Convolution Theorem**.  This optimization is even better, but it is a bit more complicated.  Basically: *a convolution in the spatial domain is equivalent to point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain.*  This means if you put your image and kernel through an FFT, your convolution can go from quadratic (naive) time complexity to O(*n* log *n*)!  Check out [Convolution theorem on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)

Answer (score 5):

Filter2d is efficient when your filter size is small, and is faster than the post you referred. However, when the kernel grows large, the runtime increases drastically.

In fact, there are many implementations that are much faster than OpenCV, including those based on recursions and integral images.

The key idea of the recursive implementation is that 2D convolution can be seperated into several 1D convolutions, and 1D convolution can be written as recursion. just google about recursive guassian filter or recursive convolution.

Also, you can decompose you kernel and implement the convolution using several integral images. just google about  kernel integral image or cosine integral image.

In either way, the runtime will not increase with the kernel size. Thus those implementations are much much more efficient than OpenCV's filter2d when your kernel is large.

Understanding the recursive implementation or the integral image implementation  requires some mathmatical background on signal processing.

If the efficiency of the implementation is your first concern, you'd better learn them and write a filter2d yourself. If not, just use opencv's filter2d, remembering avoiding large kernel.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've read about integral images when using the Viola Jones face detection code and it should be faster than convolutions. I will read more about it and see if I can use it more often.