# filter2D OpenCV function c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have noticed differences between the OpenCV implementation of filter2D in C++ and a direct implementation of the corresponding kernel. I have read the following question:

[Opencv - how does the filter2D() method actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981699/opencv-how-does-the-filter2d-method-actually-work?rq=1)

The author of that question had tried to get a working implementation of the filter2D function. He claims that using a normalized version of filters yields correct results. I have tested his hypothesis and found that normalization gives the correct answer only when all the coefficients are positive. Thus an averaging filter can be successfully implemented using the filter2D function.[We must still normalize the kernel].

However this is not the case for filters with negative coefficients such as the Sobel,Laplacian and any edge detection filter. The author of that question has encountered the same problems as me.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669614/bovaz

The user mentioned above replied to the linked question. He claimed that filter2D might modify its implementation if the sum of the coefficients of  the kernel equals zero. Is that the case? Why does the implementation of filter2D in C+ give different results from a direct implementation? I have checked that filter2D in Python and a direct implementation of the corresponding kernel in C++ yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly because of scaling and overflow issues.
The documentation for filter2D does not mention(atleast i did not find) whether the overflowed values are clipped or scaled appropriately to the min-max range.
This is more important in the case of directional filters, where the co-efficients are positive and negative and after the algebraic 
The function 'myfilter2D' presented on the link above does not scale to the min-max range which should be the case.

If you could post the sample code then it would be easier to help.

My suggestion would be to convert the matrices to float(with scaling) and perform algebraic operations because this tends to preserve the resulting values and values are not lost due to overflow or saturation.
im2double()->"perform algebraic operations"->im2uchar() for displaying

```
void im2uchar( Mat & src, Mat  & dest){ 
  double minVal, maxVal;
  minMaxLoc(src, &minVal, &maxVal); //find minimum and maximum intensities
  src.convertTo(dest, CV_8U, 255.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0/(maxVal - minVal));
  }

void im2float( Mat  & src, Mat  & dest){ 
  double minVal, maxVal;
  minMaxLoc(src, &minVal, &maxVal); //find minimum and maximum intensities
  src.convertTo(dest, CV_32F, 1.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 1.0/(maxVal - minVal));
  }
```